# No me funciona el alert() en la sentencia SI del JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

tengo un inconveniente con este código JavaScript.

Yo al input txtuser le paso un número desde el Contolador.

Estoy pidiendo al JavaScript que si el valor del input está vacío me devuelva "alert('no existe');", y si no está vacío entre al controlador.

El "alert('no existe') con SI falso no funciona, pero si funciona cuando el SI es verdadero.

ya he intentado de varias formas para validar el input, cómo lo puedo hacer para que funcionen ambas instancias?

```
<input type="hidden" readonly id="txtuser" name="txtuser" value="@itemUser.CodUser" />
```

```
<script language="JavaScript">
            function take_Out() {
                var codUlargo = document.getElementById('txtuser').value.length;
                if (codUlargo > 0) {//este funciona
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Adm/Out",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            detbtn: ''
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            location.href = '/Adm/Index';
                        },
                        error: function (request, status, error) {
                            alert(request.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {//este no funciona
                    alert('no existe CodUser.');
                }

            }
        </script>
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Puede que con añadir un = se solucione, no recuerdo bien si length devuelve 0, null u otra cosa... en cualquier caso, puedes mostrar su valor en consola y arreglar la condición correctamente en consecuencia o probar directamente con >= y yo añadiría: || !!codUlargo para validar NULL.

Comment: Saludos. Le sugiero entre el `var codUlargo ...` y el `if(codUlargo >0)` coloques `console.log(...)` a fin de revisar el valor que arroja desde el `document.getElementById('txtuser')` asi como el `value` y el `length`; probando con un escenario donde `if(codUlargo >0)` no sea mayor a cero. Igual y tus escenarios disponibles la condición no se cumple y es eso.

Comment: La consola me devuelve: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null. Pero probe con el siguiente y nada if (document.getElementById('txtuser').value != null) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

de la siguiente manera me funcionó

```
var elem = document.getElementById('txtuser');

if (typeof elem !== null && elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null)
```

Muchas gracias por el asesoramiento

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que este mal implementado de cara a las llaves, prueba con este que tiene las llaves de todos los casos:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function take_Out() {
            var codUlargo = document.getElementById('txtuser').value.length;
            if (codUlargo > 0) {//este funciona
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Adm/Out",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        detbtn: '';}
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        location.href = '/Adm/Index';
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert(request.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }else{//este no funciona
                alert('Ahora existe CodUser.');
            }

        }
    </script>
```